# How to target Dom elements in react native

Tags: react-native

Good day to anyone reading this, I wanted to ask if there was any way to target a specific dom element in react native such as this.

Tried to research but there was no clear answer.

This code was done in React.

```
  document.querySelector(
        `.node-${row}-${col}`
      ).className = `eachCell node-${row}-${col} wall`;
```